# How to make variables global in Flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, variables, dart

So I'm writing a App where I have multiple Screens in flutter, in my Main.dart I have a variable what I want to use in the whole app. It's only one so not much more, how can I make my variable global so I can use it in all my Screens?

Answer (score 0):

just define it in a file outside of a class.
But
you shouldn't do this because [global variables are bad](https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)
instead you should use a  state management technique like [provider pacakage](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Comment: Yeah! Ah thats how it works, yeah for the beginning I work with global variables even though its bad I know but its just one basic String so thanks! To learn Provider is on my to do List xD